# Ленивая загрузка карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы карта загружалась при скролле, например, за 500px до контейнера с ней. Сейчас получается так, что ее высота равна высоте всего скролла проекта

```js
let mapLoaded = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', lazyLoadMap);

function lazyLoadMap() {
  let scrollY = window.scrollY;
  let mapOffset = document.querySelector("#map").offsetTop;
  if ((scrollY >= mapOffset - 500) && (!mapLoaded)) {
    ymaps.ready(function() {
      var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
          center: [55.759927, 37.604098],
          zoom: 14
        }, {
          searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
          hintContent: 'Мы здесь',
          balloonContent: 'Леонтьевский переулок'
        }, {
          iconLayout: 'default#image',
          iconImageHref: 'img/icon-map.svg',
          iconImageSize: [20, 20],
          iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        });

      myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemark)

      myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
      myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl');
      myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl');
      myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl');
      myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector');
      myMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');
    });
    mapLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts__map" id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: Так а в чём вопрос? Как сделать проект длиннее? ...скролл всегда видимым? ...определить его наличие? Или что?

Comment: в том, чтобы загрузить карту только когда до нее останется 500px

Comment: А может тебе не стоит этого делать? *Может воспользуешься уже готовым атрибутом для `<iframe loading="lazy">` и не будешь париться с этим... на мобильном тоже тебя ждут приключения, поскольку длинна твоей страницы на разных мобилках будет разной + отслеживание скрола это очень дорогой по продуктивности трекер

Comment: Loading lazy не поддерживается сафари, iframe тоже не могу, только вот так. Спасибо за продуктивность по скроллу, да, как-то упустил такой момент. Если честно, можно и без всяких выкрутасов подключить, но раз уж взялся)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 можно использовать debounce для отслеживания скролла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо добавить контент перед картой, чтобы появился отслеживаемый скролл.

```
<div id="before_map" style="width: 600px; height: 2000px"></div>
```

Затем следует начать определять ещё и высоту видимой части экрана, иначе не узнать, сколько от нижнего края страницы до карты.

```
let viewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Ну а дальше останется лишь чуть скорректировать вашу строку для загрузки:

```
if ((scrollY >= mapOffset - 500 - viewHeight) && (!mapLoaded)) {...}
```

Подправленный пример: https://jsfiddle.net/sgpoeh5q/